# How to select notebook by default in Gnote

Tags: gnote

When I create link to new note in Gnote, I have to change the notebook manually. Can I change set the default notebook for every new note?

[image: Close look at screenshot]

See also [full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF6Ou.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command line option `--open-note=title` for Gnote, which will display the existing note matching title. This by itself will *not* set the note as default.

**How it works**

To see how the option works, the note must have appropriate title and run Gnote from command line.

1. First, create a new note in Gnote by clicking **New** button in headerbar or toolbar, or click Gnote menu ➜ **New note** (appearance may vary by desktop environment).
2. Then, change the note title from "New Note 1" to title of choice i.e. "Test New Note". The title is *not* case sensitive i.e. "new note" and "New Note" are same in Gnote.

   [image: Gnote with a new note]
3. Open a Terminal or an application launcher, type the command i.e. `gnote --open-note="Test New Note"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The note i.e. "Test New Note" will open directly.

   [image: Gnote open the new note directly]

**Pseudo default**

To open Gnote with the pseudo default note, user can either use system-wide application shortcuts, or use application menu (configuration may vary by desktop environment).

- Using system-wide application shortcuts, for example, I have assigned <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> as shortcut to run the command.

  [image: Application shortcuts in Xubuntu]
- Using application menu, for example, I have created a new launcher using MenuLibre menu editor and the launcher is accessible from both application menu and application launcher.

  [image: Application menu and launcher in Xubuntu]

**Additional notes**

By default, Gnote keep notes created by user at `~/.local/share/gnote/`. If user wanted to open notes from elsewhere, use another option `--note-path=path` to create a new note directory first.

- To create new note directory i.e. `~/Notebooks`:

  ```
  gnote --note-path="Notebooks"
  ```
- To create new note directory with subdirectory i.e. `~/Notebooks/Project1`:

  ```
  gnote --note-path="Notebooks/Project1"
  ```

Then, create a new note and change the title i.e. "coding". Close the note and Gnote window. This time, to open the "coding" note, append the earlier option `--open-note=title`.

```
gnote --note-path="Notebooks/Project1" --open-note="coding"
```

Similarly, run the command in a Terminal or an application launcher. Also, the command can be added to system-wide application shortcuts with shortcut keys of choice to open the pseudo default note.

Tested using Gnote 3.10.3 in Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Comment on *Additional Notes* section, possibly helpful to others:

Quote:

> By default, Gnote keep notes created by user at
>   ~/.local/share/gnote/. If user wanted to open notes from elsewhere,
>   use another option --note-path=path to create a new note directory
>   first.
>       To create new note directory i.e. ~/Notebooks:
>       gnote --note-path="Notebooks"

Yes, this works, but it doesn't allow control over placing the new directory in gnote's default location -- or elsewhere, wherever the user may desire.

I wanted to keep all gnote directories together and made these notes to follow, if I ever have to do it again:

Create a new data directory system.
$ gnote --note-path="gnote-memos" (name given, as example.)

Only a file name is relevant, *as gnote will always, uncontrollably, put it directly off of ~/ directory* -- no matter what the user requests for the path.  So, in my experience, the word 'path' in this parameter's name is *misleading*.

Be careful of the '~' as it doesn't always work, in all locations.

Cut this newly-created directory, looking for the name you gave it -- as it will *not* be in gnote's default data file location.

Paste it into the desired directory of your own choice, with a preference for original default directory, i.e.:
~/.local/share/gnote

Start gnote from terminal, or edit the original menu entry, to show the path to the data files:

```
~$ gnote --note-path ~/.local/share/gnote
```

to start gnote with original data.
Then make another menu entry (or enter at terminal) the above line, with the new directory's name:
`~$ gnote --note-path ~/.local/share/gnote-memo`  (new filename given as example).
Starting gnote as usual, *without a path specification,* may now be erratic in determining which data set it opens.  This should not happen, but in my experience gnote was'flipping back-and-forth' between the old, and new, data sets for the first few runs.  Therefore, always specify.

---

System info:
gnote v.3.10.3, 
Bodhi Linux